# Plot simple time axis for events

Tags: r, ggplot2, unix-timestamp

I'm looking for a solution to plot a time axis where events are marked as red vertical lines. I didn't find anything like that:

[image]
(the height of the red lines should be equal)

The data is just a list of unix timestamps which should be plotted as red strings between a timespan.

How to plot using ggplot?

Comment: I do not know the best tool in R. But in python, you would find most in the "seaborn" package: http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-univariate-distributions

Comment: Here is the start `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = -1, xend = hp, yend = 1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_segment(col = "red") +
  theme_classic()`

Comment: thank you very much! Do you have some data of mtcars? This would help me to understand how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here are some sample dates:

```
sampleDates <-
  sample(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01")
             , as.Date("2016-12-31")
             , 1)
         , 60)
```

Then, here is an extension of the starting point from @zx8754's comment (note: `mtcars` is a builtin data set). Here, I add an arrow (instead of just a line), then use `geom_linerange` because you can get a vertical line in the legend, e.g., if you are coloring lines by event type. Everything from `theme_minimal` down is just shifting display options to make it prettier.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = min(sampleDates) - 10
        , xend = max(sampleDates) + 20
        , y = 0
        , yend = 0)
    , arrow = arrow()
  ) +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(x = sampleDates
        , ymin = -1
        , ymax = 1)
    , col = "red") +
  xlab("Sample Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()
        , axis.title.y = element_blank()
        , panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()
        , panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
        ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month"
               , date_labels = "%Y\n%b-%d")
```

[image]